# How to validate form element generated by js in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I want to allow users to add textbox element using javascript by clicking the add button.

I would like to know how I can use Zend validate to validate those elements that are created by javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way for that but it shouldn't be too tricky to do this.

Firstly, I would suggest naming your JavaScript-generated elements with array notation, ie. `name='someName[]'`, so that PHP parses them into an array in POST/GET.

Then, you can simply loop over the resulting array, and call your validator(s)/validator chain.

Answer (score 0):

addPrefix to the new added and then check for prefixed keys in $_POST and add the fields to the form. There is no easy way to do this.